# Internet Shortcut like steam:// in c#

Tags: c#, shortcut, launch

As you know games on steam can be launched in browser with "steam://rungameid/".

How can I add something like that (for example myprogram://run/form1) in my C# program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a "URI Scheme" having your program open with one is as simple as adding a few registry entries in the correct places.

The documentation for creating one can be found [on the msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) but for your example it should roughly look like

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   myprogram
      (Default) = "URL:My Program"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "MyProgram.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\My Program\MyProgram.exe" "%1"
```

Once done following one of those "links" will launch your program and pass the uri in as a command line argument. So, for your example of `myprogram://run/form1` your program would be launched as if you did from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\My Program\MyProgram.exe" "//run/form1"
```